# opengl with windows 8

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, opengl

I just installed windows 8 and microsoft visual studio 2012. The problem comes when I try to run a program, it tells me:

> the program can't start because glu32.dll is missing from your computer. try reinstalling the program to fix this problem

But I have already placed the `glu32.dll` in the locations that it should.

Answer (score 0):

The graphics drivers shipping with Windows 8 lack proper OpenGL support. You **must** download the drivers from your GPU vendors website directly and install those.

Also when manually adding missing DLLs you should not add them to system directories, but into right into the directory of the application's `.exe` files.

Comment: _Also when manually adding missing DLLs you should not add them to system directories, but into right into the directory of the application's .exe files._ and that's how every Windows application comes with all it's required DLLs and why there is a huge waste of space since every dll is duplicated. A sound advice on your side, don't get me wrong, but due to a poor design on Microsoft's side.

Comment: @Shahbaz: It's called *DLL-Hell* for a reason. Anyway, a lot of capable OS design researchers agree these days that shared objects / DLLs were a terrible idea on a system level. Plugins are better implemented using separated processes and IPC.